# Batch create subfolders inside parent folders, incorporating name of parent folder into the subfolder name

Tags: batch-processing, directory, subdirectory, bulk

I've done my best to search for an answer to this but please forgive me if it exists as I'm a little new to this.

I'm trying to batch-create subfolders inside parent folders, incorporating the name of parent folder into the subfolder names. I'm using Windows 7.

So, I have a parent folder, `Candybars`

Inside the Candybars folder are hundreds of subfolders in the following format:

`Candybars\firstword secondword possiblethirdword occasionalfourthword`

Note that the subfolder names have spaces between the words. Some have just two words, (eg `kitkat` `swiss`) and some have three (eg `kitkat` `swiss` `yummy`) or occasionally four.

I'd like to put a subfolder in each of the existing subfolders, using the full name of the parent as part of the name of the subfolder, eg:

`Candybars\firstword secondword\firstword secondword illustrations`

So I might end up with something like:

`Candybars\chocolate\chocolate illustrations
Candybars\kitkat swiss\kitkat swiss illustrations
Candybars\kitkat swiss yummy\kitkat swiss yummy illustrations
Candybars\special chocolate\special chocolate illustrations
Candybars\very special chocolate\very special chocolate illustrations`

I would be monumentally grateful for any help with this. I'm going round in circles!

Thanks, Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PowerShell. Create a file in the Candybars directory called, say, Subdirs.ps1 with contents:

```
Get-ChildItem |
where {$_.PsIsContainer} | 
foreach {new-item -Name ($_.name + "\" + $_.name + " illustrations") -ItemType directory}
```

Then you can right-click on the file in Windows Explorer and select Run with PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks so much NickN!  That worked perfectly. I grateful and in awe. Jon